# How to prove the comparision theorem for the viscosity solution of degenerate elliptic PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to prove the comparision theorem for the viscosity solution of the following equation:
$$
\lambda u(x,y)−\Delta_xu(x,y)−b(y)\cdot\nabla_yu(x,y)=f(x,y),
$$
with b only in certain Holder space. I am a geginner on the study of viscosity solution, so I want to choose this equation as an exercise. But I can not solove it. Many thanks.

Comment: Just Fourier transform in $x$ and use the method of characteristics?

Comment: The viscosity solution may not have the required regularities. Thanks.

Comment: You should fully specify this problem (i.e., boundary conditions, domain, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The equation is considered in the whole R^d. I want to show every bounded subsolution <= supersolution.